# Uploading files on web from client without revealing API key

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, rest, scribd

I'm trying to upload a file from a web application to an external source (such as scribd) for example. to upload the file I need to send the API key as well. however if i send the API key from the client it will be revealed to users who search for it on the client side.

How could I upload from client using an API key that I don't want to reveal to users? It seems redundant to upload it to my server and then to the external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As redundant as it may be to pass through your server, it's the only way. You can't use the key client-side and hide it from the client, and if you don't use HTTPS it can easily be intercepted too. As a side note, I don't know about Scribd but usually stealing API keys is not very useful, so you may just live with the "risk".

**Edit:**
apparently Scribd offers a way to provide encrypted requests so that your API key can't be deduced by them (you have to generate these remotely and send them to the client of course). See http://www.scribd.com/developers/api?method_name=Signing

Comment: Actually in most cases stealing an API key is the only thing you need. Even in this simply case you can use the API key to upload files. Uploading files usually also implies that you can delete files through the same API:.

Comment: In that case the API must offer some additional security measure. Reading the Scribd doc, I found that you can use Request Signing http://www.scribd.com/developers/api?method_name=Signing, so that should solve the original poster's problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. That does solve my problem. My question was general, but my problem was specific.